# Why does line-height property not work with hyperlinks?

Tags: html, css

This is the html code for the hyperlinks. I wanted to have a slight gap between the texts. Like between 'Menu' and 'Contact Us' for instance. Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="navbar">

    <a class="fb" href="menu.html">Menu</a></br>
    <a href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a></br>
    <a href="About Us.html">About Us</a></br>
    <a href="TC.html">Terms & Conditions</a></br>
    <a href="jobs.html" target="_blank">Jobs</a></br>
    <a href="order.html">Your Order</a>

</div>
```

I set the line-height property in CSS as follows:

```css
#navbar {
  line-height:2em;
}
```

Comment: give css `div#navbar a{padding-left: 5px;}` it will solve your problem

Comment: Oh noted. Thanks for the link @Phrogz =)

Comment: Yup, I had the same problem.  Shailender's solution (below), wrapping each "a href" in a <li> solved it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should define a line-height in **anchor** not in **navbar** id see the example code:-

**HTML**

```
<div id="navbar">

<a class="fb" href="menu.html">Menu</a></br>
<a href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a></br>
<a href="About Us.html">About Us</a></br>
<a href="TC.html">Terms & Conditions</a></br>
<a href="jobs.html" target="_blank">Jobs</a></br>
<a href="order.html">Your Order</a>
```

**CSS**

```
#navbar a {
color: red;
line-height: 33px;
text-decoration: none;
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/8LFLd/50/

And the other proper method is i am mentioning below you should make navigation in proper ul li list items like mentioned below:-

**HTML**

```
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="fb" href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="About Us.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="TC.html">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
    <li><a href="jobs.html" target="_blank">Jobs</a></li>
    <li><a href="order.html">Your Order</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#navbar li {
    display:block;
    list-style-type:none;
    line-height:25px;
}
#navbar li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:red;
}
#navbar li a.fb {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:green;
}

#navbar li a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:blue;
}
```

demo:- http://jsfiddle.net/XZ9w7/3/

Comment: The purpose of the other method is to avoid using HTML when styling content right ? ( in this case, </br> )

Comment: @TheKraven no the purpose of other method is its a proper markup for navigation whenever we need a navigation so we should make the proper makeup with HTML & CSS its not avoiding the HTML.

That's y i gave you two anwsers first one was based as per your question and second i made from my side in proper way....

Answer (score 8):

Don't use `<br/>` (which you've mistyped consistently) and `line-height`, use a list and adjust the margins on the list items.

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/psP7L/

```html
<ul id="navbar">
  <li><a class="fb" href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
  <li><a href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="About Us.html">About Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="TC.html">Terms & Conditions</a></li>
  <li><a href="jobs.html" target="_blank">Jobs</a></li>
  <li><a href="order.html">Your Order</a></li>
</ul>
```

```css
#navbar    { padding:0; margin:0 }
#navbar li { display:block; padding:0; margin:0.3em 0 }
```

*Proper, semantic markup first; then get the styling right.*

---

However, to answer your question, it does "work", it's just that `line-height` on `display:inline` elements [behaves differently per the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) than it does for `display:block` elements.

Comment: Are Hyperlinks inline elements ? Thanks alot for the clear clarification.

Answer (score 5):

You have to apply the style to the anchor, and add `display:block;` to your CSS to make this work:

```
#navbar a{
  line-height: 2em;
  display: block;
}
```

Amongst some other fixes in your code you should end up with something like in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/psP7L/10/).

Answer (score 1):

```
#navbar a{ display:block;line-height:30px;}
```

Remove

demo http://jsfiddle.net/psP7L/1/